# Android location Update not working when app is on background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, location

Android 12 Location updates not working when app is on background. and work fine when app is on forground.

I also "allow all time" permission for for location. Acc to docs after this location updates start work on background. but in my case it stop updates when app is on foreground.

### locationUpdatePendingIntent

```
    private val locationUpdatePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
    val intent = Intent(context, LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    intent.action = LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
}
```

Firstly I use Location Request. inside Automatic Workmanager

```
val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 0L)
    .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)

    .build()
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        context.applicationContext,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        context,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
) {
    return Result.success();
}
fusedLocationProviderClient?.requestLocationUpdates(
    mLocationRequest,
    locationUpdatePendingIntent
)
```

then listen to location updates used inside  Automatic Workmanager

```
override fun onLocationUpdate(location: Location) {
    val executor: ExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    executor.execute {
        lastLocation = location
        updateLocation()
    }
}
```

Location update broadcast (in this location update)

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.location.Location
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationAvailability
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult


class LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    private  val TAG = "LocationUpdatesBroadcas";
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() context:$context, intent:$intent")

        if (intent?.action == ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES) {

            // Checks for location availability changes.
            LocationAvailability.extractLocationAvailability(intent)?.let { locationAvailability ->
                if (!locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Location services are no longer available!")
                }
            }

            LocationResult.extractResult(intent)?.let { locationResult ->
                Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: lastLocation ${locationResult.locations.size}", )
                if(locationResult.lastLocation != null){
                    ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker.INSTANCE?.reciveLocation(locationResult.lastLocation!!)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES =
            "action." +
                    "PROCESS_UPDATES"
    }

    interface UpdatedLocation{
        fun onLocationUpdate(location: Location)
    }
}

class ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker(var updateLocation: LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.UpdatedLocation){
    private  val TAG = "LocationUpdatesBroadcas"

    fun reciveLocation( location:Location){
        Log.e(TAG, "reciveLocation:--- ${location} " )
        updateLocation.onLocationUpdate(location)
    }


    companion object {
        var INSTANCE: ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker? = null

        fun getInstance(updateLocation: LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.UpdatedLocation): ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker(
                    updateLocation )
                    .also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing  **"AutomaticLocationWorker"** to **"AutomaticLocationBackgroundService:LifecycleService()"** or change worker to lifecycleService.

private var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null

```
    private val locationUpdatePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(this, LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        intent.action = LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
    }
```

```
  fusedLocationProviderClient?.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest,
            locationUpdatePendingIntent
        )
```

### LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver

```
class LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    private  val TAG = "LocationUpdatesBroadcas";
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() context:$context, intent:$intent")

        if (intent?.action == ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES) {

            // Checks for location availability changes.
            LocationAvailability.extractLocationAvailability(intent)?.let { locationAvailability ->
                if (!locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Location services are no longer available!")
                }
            }

            LocationResult.extractResult(intent)?.let { locationResult ->
                Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: lastLocation ${locationResult.locations.size}", )
                if(locationResult.lastLocation != null){
                    ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker.INSTANCE?.reciveLocation(locationResult.lastLocation!!)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES =
            "com.commuteoptm.bcos.background_services.action." +
                    "PROCESS_UPDATES"
    }

    interface UpdatedLocation{
        fun onLocationUpdate(location: Location)
    }
}
```

### ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker

```
class ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker(var updateLocation: LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.UpdatedLocation){
    private  val TAG = "LocationUpdatesBroadcas"

    fun reciveLocation( location:Location){
        Log.e(TAG, "reciveLocation:--- ${location} " )
        updateLocation.onLocationUpdate(location)
    }


    companion object {
        var INSTANCE: ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker? = null

        fun getInstance(updateLocation: LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.UpdatedLocation): ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: ShareLocationToAutomaticWorker(
                    updateLocation )
                    .also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share full example??

Comment: It is the same as code is provided, but also you need to startForground by  notification  @RameshBhati

Comment: @SahilKumar, Please provide a full code because this code is not enough.

Comment: @VishalDasadiya , I am unable to provide you with the full code at the moment. However, I can assist you with your issue. You just need to initiate a service and implement a notification to start the foreground service, which will allow the service to run in the background. You can follow this codelab; it will be helpful: [Google Location Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/while-in-use-location#0).

Comment: here is full example github: https://github.com/joostfunkekupper/background-location-sample-ktx but this will not work in background it will work in foreground.